# Null values in datset

Tags: python

I'm using a dataset to predict the effects on the economy because of covid-19. The dataset contains 9k rows and around 1k rows in each column is empty. Do I need to fill them manually by looking at other datasets online or can I fill the average or should I leave the dataset as it is?

Comment: OK, as I said you can read [ask], and the [help] in general. Sorry if it seemed aggresive, I was trying to help you write better questions that fit this website... Sometimes is hard to express with written words. I am deeply sorry and hope you will find this website to good use! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'd say that combining datasets from multiple sources without being really clear about your rational can raise pretty big questions about the reliability of your data.

Otherwise, either assuming averages or leaving null are both valid options depending on what you're trying to do. If you're using scikit learn (eg) you'll probably find that nulls throw up errors, so filling with assumed averages is a relatively common thing to do. Although you might want to watch out given you've got more that 10% nulls!

From experience, I'd say think about what you're trying to do, and what will help you get there best. Then be really clear about presenting your methodology with your findings.